# Connect VB.Net Project to Smarterasp

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Can we connect VB.Net project o database that have been created in SMARTERASP?
I have tried once but it always appear error52.

> error:52 - Unable to locate a local database runtime installation.
>   verify that sql server express is properly installed and that the
>   local database runtime feature is enable

sql server express local database runtime

sql server express local database runtime feature is enabled

Comment: is that the hosting site?

Comment: If you're hosting your site with a third party then they will tell you what connection string to use. You likely cannot attach a local data file on demand, but rather have to create an always-attached database. You need to talk to them though, not us.

Comment: You have tried once - perhaps share the code you have tried.